# Special case of collapse OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a potentially simple question, but looking at SO I couldn't find any questions that asked quite the same thing. My question is: **will the `collapse` clause in the OpenMP code below properly handle both inner loops?** Or will it only collapse with the first inner loop?

```
!$omp parallel do collapse(2) private(iy, ix, iz)
do iy = 1, ny
    do ix = 1, nx
       ! stuff
    enddo
    do iz = 1, nz
       ! different stuff
    enddo
enddo
!$omp end parallel do
```

This code compiles for me and obviously shows benefits of parallelization. However, I know that the standard says:

> All loops associated with the loop construct must be perfectly nested; that is, there must be no intervening code nor any OpenMP directive between any two loops.

So my gut reaction is that OpenMP is only collapsing the first inner loop (`ix`). But then how is it handling the second inner loop (`iz`)?

I am obviously attempting the code to do the following, but it is much uglier and verbose to write the code this way:

```
!$omp parallel private(iy, ix, iz)
!$omp do collapse(2)
do iy = 1, ny
    do ix = 1, nx
       ! stuff
    enddo
enddo
!$omp end do nowait

!$omp do collapse(2)
do iy = 1, ny
    do iz = 1, nz
       ! different stuff
    enddo
enddo
!$omp end do nowait
!$omp end parallel do
```

Comment: nowait on the second do does nothing since parallel end has barrier semantics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first inner loop is code intervening between the outer loop and the second inner loop (as I understand it).  If `nz`≠`nx`, you don’t have rectangular loops.  In any case, the program semantics are that the first inner loop must complete before the second inner loop begins; it might perform intermediate calculations that the second loop uses.  A given implementation of OpenMP *might* do what you want—I haven’t attempted to test this.

Note that the second example changes the semantics of the program: all the `ix` loops execute, followed by all the `iz` loops, rather than each `ix` loop followed by each `iz` loop for the same value of `iy`.  This should be safe if you could parallelize the `ix` loop, as you can only do that if none of the `ix` computations depend on any `iz` computation, but might not be as efficient if the `iz` loops are going to re-use the same data.  So the correct semantics are going to depend on what needs to happen before a given loop can run.  Do the `iz` loops need the `ix` loops to have run first for the same value of `iy`?  If not, you might be able to use nested parallelism.

**Note on Loop Collapsing:** Loop collapsing usually means you take a nested pair of loops, such as,

```
for (i=0;i<100;++i)
  for (j=0;j<50;++j)
```

And turn them into a single loop like:

```
for (ij=0;ij<5000;++ij)
```

If you have two different inner loops with different indices, you cannot do this, and furthermore, the compiler can’t automatically change the order of execution as proposed because that changes program semantics.  I’m not sure what every OpenMP implementation does with this code, but I’m pretty sure that it doesn’t work the way you were hoping.

Comment: I disagree on some points. The "rectangular loops" argument is faulty because if (as I hope) each inner loop is being collapsed independently, then the two loops are rectangular. That is how I personally would interpret `collapse(2)` to mean in this context at least.

Comment: Furthermore, notice that there is a `end do nowait` after the first loop in what I hope to be the final result. This means that not every `iy` iteration of the first loop is guaranteed to finish before a thread starts its portion of the second loop. Aka the semantics of what I hope the answer are: the second loop does not depend on the first loop's computation.

Comment: Okay.  I don’t think the compiler can automatically deduce that `nowait` should be there, though.